# Extract only one field from JSON with R

Tags: r, dataframe, rjson

I recently created a function that is calling an API and gives the following results (json format):

```
{"data":{"loc":"google.fr","lang":"fr","domain":"domain.com","result":[["voyage thailande",1,"https://www.blabla.com/thailande/"]]}}
```

My purpose is to get a data.frame with "only" the last part of the after the "result":

```
voyage thailande, 0, https://www.blabla.com/thailande/
```

Right now I only succeeded to get the following data.frame (see the picture):[image]

With the following code:

```
library(rjson)
keyword_checker <- function(keyword, domain, loc, lang){

  keyword_to_check <- as.character(keyword)

  api_request <- paste("https://script.fromgoogle.....",
                       "?kw=",keyword,
                       "&domain=",domain,
                       "&loc=",loc,
                       "&lang=",lang,sep="")
  api_request <- URLencode(api_request, repeated = TRUE)  
  source <-fromJSON(file = api_request)#Convertir un Json file en Data Frame
  return(data.frame(do.call("rbind", source)))
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `source$data$result` will return the requested information.

Comment: thank you! I just tested it with `source$result` that's why it wasn't working

Comment: So, as I said, this is working fine now, but I have another problem... In my data, instead of a vector, I have a list. how is that possible considering that I used the `data.frame`?

Comment: `fromJson` function is returning a hierarchical list of lists.  The data.frame function is just packing the sub-lists into the cells of the data frame so you many need to `unlist` function to finish cleaning the data.  I suggest, asking another question providing a larger sample size and a better explanation of the desired result.